# Banner DIV is not moving down

Tags: html, css

I've been trying to move down my banner div (.banner) and have no idea what I'm doing wrong. I've tried padding-bottom,padding-top and margins I'm not sure what is getting in the way of me being able to move it down. I've also tried to move my nav down to see if that is the problem but the banner still wont move down.

Image of what I'm trying to do:

[image]

```css
body {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.nav {
  background-color: #gray;
  color: black;
  list-style: none;
  text-align: right;
}

.nav > li {
  display: inline-block;
  padding-right: 0px;
  font-size: 20px;
  margin-right: 20px;
}

.nav > li > a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
}

.nav > li > a:hover {
  opacity: .5;
}

.banner {
  background-color: gray;
  width: 100%;
  height: 400px;
  padding-bottom: 15px;
}
```

```html
<div class="banner">
  <ul class="nav">
    <li><a href="##">Gallery</a></li>
    <li><a href="###">About</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: can you explain more ? what is the expected result ?

Comment: What I'm trying to do is move the banner and nav down as one. The result I want is the nav to be inside the banner and for both of them to move down the page. When I do so now the banner and nav don't move down together and I'm not quite sure why.

Comment: you tried margin-top on banner ?

Comment: `.banner {margin-top: 25px;}` pushes the banner down the page.  If this does not work for you, or is not what you want, then you need to get specific and include a code sample that actually **demonstrates the problem**, as well as what you have tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ran your code snippet and added `margin-top: 100px` to the `.banner` element which successfully pushed the content down. Did you try this?

Perhaps you could make a live link for a us to preview the issue in case there is something else interfering?

Answer (score 0):

Use `margin-top` to create distance above a DIV:

```css
body {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.nav {
  background-color: #gray;
  color: black;
  list-style: none;
  text-align: right;
}

.nav > li {
  display: inline-block;
  padding-right: 0px;
  font-size: 20px;
  margin-right: 20px;
}

.nav > li > a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
}

.nav > li > a:hover {
  opacity: .5;
}

.banner {
  background-color: gray;
  width: 100%;
  height: 400px;
  padding-bottom: 15px;
  margin-top: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="banner">
  <ul class="nav">
    <li><a href="##">Gallery</a></li>
    <li><a href="###">About</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

## Problem

Are you sure, you did use the `margin-top` property?

## Solving

Just replace the .banner `padding` for the `margin-top` property.

```css
body {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.nav {
  background-color: gray;
  color: black;
  list-style: none;
  text-align: right;
}

.nav > li {
  display: inline-block;
  padding-right: 0px;
  font-size: 20px;
  margin-right: 20px;
}

.nav > li > a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
}

.nav > li > a:hover {
  opacity: .5;
}

.banner {
  background-color: red;
  width: 100%;
  height: 400px;
  margin-top: 150px;
}
```

```html
<div class="banner">
  <ul class="nav">
    <li><a href="##">Gallery</a></li>
    <li><a href="###">About</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

## Useful links

- [Shay Howe](https://learn.shayhowe.com/html-css/opening-the-box-model/) teaches the box model (Width, padding, margin, etc...).